# (RegEx-)Replace: Sporadic Match data clobbered by buffer modification hooks

Tags: debugging, flycheck, query-replace, match-data

I know this was asked in other contexts already, but I couldn't find anything related to **C++** development with my hooks that could help me.
I am working a lot with `replace` and `query-replace` and `query-replace-regexp` and I love it.

Now I have the very annoying problem that after a while I am working in a buffer I suddenly get the error mentioned in the title after the first replace.

This happens not always but after a while it suddenly appears. Reopening the buffer fixes it for a while but is not a solution.

In other answers the `before-changes-functions` and the `after-change-functions` are mentioned. Because the error occurs after the first replace, I would assume it should be located in the `after-change-functions` hook. The value for this in the buffer is:

```
(c-after-change flycheck-handle-change flymake-after-change-function lsp-on-change jit-lock-after-change t)
```

I failed to find out what is going on there, so any help on that is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Alex Karbivnichiy for the answer. I like your idea of a custom replace.

It inspired me to do some more testing with `before-change-functions` and `after-change-functions` without success. I had a buffer with the clobbered problem and started to disable minor modes. Nothing helped. I then set both change functions to nil and even this did not solve the problem.

I killed and reopened the buffer and replace is working as expected again.

Am I missing any other variable or function that can cause this problem.

Comment: Try to disable one package at a time and check if the problem goes away. Once you find the culprit you can contact the package maintainer.

Comment: Next stage would be a description of how to replicate the bug/artifact. That can take time, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsp-on-change` probably connects to a server(Language Server Protocol) on each change:

https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/9b5511dbf187348d00be8815d5b7533732f164d6/lsp-mode.el#L1658

`c-after-change` doc in comments, excerpt:

> We can sometimes get two consecutive calls to `after-change-functions` without an
>   intervening call to `before-change-functions` when reverting the buffer
>   (see bug #24094).  Whatever the cause, assume that the entire buffer has changed.

So due to a lot of unknown runtime context it can be fragile.

A solution to investigate or enhance would be creation of custom wrappers around *replace* functions, disabling `after-change-functions` during those function execution.
In `c-mode` hook:

```el
(defun my-query-replace-regexp ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((after-change-functions nil)) ; empty when executing this func
    (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp)))

(define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-M-%") 'my-query-replace-regexp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late reaction. I know this thread is quite old now. Just saw it right now and it is fair enough to accept your great answer.